# Can't place objects everywhere on the TabControl

Tags: c#, tabcontrol

When I try to add something on my `TabControl` in certain places, it automatically moves it into another Tab.

For example I can add a `Label' here:

[image]

But not here:

[image]

It automatically moves to the other Tab when I add it in the middle.

Comment: Hmm, that's too unusual.  First reboot your machine.  Next try setting the Alignment property to Top.

Comment: Yeah I've rebooted my computer multiple times. And on what should I set alignement to top?

Comment: Okey. It works when I have "Alignement top" but I need it to be alignement left for my design.. Any idea on how I can fix this problem?

Comment: Oh wait, what the ...? When I changed alignement to left and then back to top it now works.. O.o Thank you! (y)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hah, thank you Hans Passant for the answere. I'll write it here as an answere if someone else get this "bug". How I fixed it:
Change the tabcontrol from alignemnt Left to Top and then back to Left again.

Idk why it works but it does (y) :D

EDIT: wait... now it dosn't work again?.. crap

NEW EDIT: OK.  Now I figured out what was causing it.  I was using VB power packs and when I removed that it now works  (y)